# AQ propagation between databases with different NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS

Tags: database, oracle, types, plsql, advanced-queuing

Is it possible to propagate AQ messages between two databases which have different `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`, i.e. LOCAL database have BYTE(`nls_database_parameters` view) and REMOTE database have CHAR(`nls_database_parameters` view), if so then how? I've already tried setting session `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter value to `BYTE` and then recreating REMOTE database AQ OBJECT_TYPE, overriding object type attribute declarations with BYTE and creating OID type in local database and using transform in propagation, but it didn't work out, still getting

> "ORA-25215: user_data type and queue type do not match"

upon propagation.

This is object type that i'm using in AQ table's:

```
create or replace type obj_sepa_msg as object
(
  client    varchar2(50),
  cartridge varchar2(20),
  iban      varchar2(34),
  file_name varchar2(4000),
  data      clob
)
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the columns to use an explicit length semantics (i.e. `varchar2(50 CHAR)` or `varchar2(50 BYTE)`) on each side?  I would expect that to work though I don't have an environment to test in at the moment.

Comment: Yes, i've tried it, still no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to propagate between databases with different `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`, but only system variable payload's, like `sys.xmltype` or `sys.number`. However you can't put them into `object type` if you're using database version 11.2.0.3 or less. If you need object types you could do something like this. When propagating to remote database add transformation to subscriber so it would transform your `object type` to `sys.xmltype` before propagating, note that you still need to specify that payload will be `sys.xmltype`. Then upon dequeing message in remote database you can specify transformation in `dbms_aq.message_properties_t type`, to transform `sys.xmltype` to your desired payload.